# TinyMCE: how to dynamically hide/show toolbar buttons after initialization?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

With TinyMCE 4.1.7 I was able to hide and show toolbar buttons after initialization like this, eg. to only show a special "save" button in fullscreen (trust me, I need buttons like this):

```
editor.addButton('custom_fullscreen_save', {
    text: 'Save',
    icon: false,
    onPostRender: function() {
        tButtons.saveFullScreen = this;
        this.hide();  //initially hide the button
    },
    onclick: function() {
        //...
    }
});
```

`tButtons` is my own variable that I use to keep a reference to the button, so that I can then do this later on to show the button:

```
tButtons.saveFullScreen.show();
```

But now that I have upgraded to 4.7.13 the toolbar layout goes crazy when I do that and doesn't render properly. It pretty much initially renders the toolbar area size and buttons as if those buttons were visible. It's like it doesn't "rerender" the toolbar after the buttons are made visible.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: TinyMCE re-wrote the UI layer since 4.1.7 so the new design likely does not like the adding/removing of buttons like you have done.  Can you enable/disable the button instead?

Comment: @MichaelFromin The buttons will have text that the user will be confused about - and as we all know things have to extremely simple for the end-user, so the answer to that will have to be a "no".

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Did you fix this?I have the same scenario.